# WEB RTC VIDEO Conferencing

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Using web rtc how can one change the video panels width and height as they are  calculated in `getmediaelement.js` file and it change the height of both video panels i.e sender and receiver?

So I want to increase the height of receiver but decrease the height of sender and vice versa.

How it can be done?

```js
var b = document.createElement("div");
b.className = "media-box";
i.appendChild(b);
b.appendChild(e);
if (!t.width) t.width = innerWidth / 2 - 50;
i.style.width = t.width + "px";
if (t.height) {
    b.style.height = t.height + "px"
}
```

Comment: Could you provide us more code ? The page template for example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that you pasted refers to a div and it's not relevant. The WebRTC peer is usually displayed in a video tag and that one you can modify it as any HTML element, even through CSS.

As for the video resolution that you send to other parties can be controlled using `getUserMedia` constraints. What you receive can be controlled of course by the other party.